# onclick method add both bind and parameter

Tags: javascript

I have 2 methods. displayBookmark and deleteBookmarks. Currently I have onclick event that executes my deleteBookmark() method and also executes this.displayBookmark(). Without binding "this" element i couldn't execute this.displayBookmark(). My question how to get url parameter to deleteBookmark method?
I can't make it work on codepen so I will include [github link](https://github.com/ArnasDickus/web-helper/blob/master/src/scripts/views/bookmark.js)

`${onclick = this.deleteBookmark.bind(this)}`

```
displayBookmark(){


   this.bookmarksResults.innerHTML = ``;
   for (let index = 0; index < bookmarks.length; index++) {
        let name = (bookmarks[index].siteName).charAt(0).toUpperCase() + bookmarks[index].siteName.slice(1);
        let url = bookmarks[index].siteUrl;

     elements.bookmarksResults.innerHTML += 
    `
    <ul>
        <li><h2 ><a class = "bookmarkResults__title" href="${url}" target = "_blank">${name}</a></h2> 
        <a ${onclick = this.deleteBookmark.bind(this)} class = "button button__delete">Delete</a>
        <a class = "button button__edit">Edit</a>
        <a class = "button button__visit" href="${url}" target = "_blank">Visit</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
    `
   }

}
deleteBookmark(){     

 console.log(url);  
 this.displayBookmark();      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody already gave me a good solution but it didn't worked for me and as a result a guy deleted his comment. But he was right. Basically I needed to modify these lines.

```
${onclick = this.deleteBookmark.bind(this, url)}

deleteBookmark(url){     

console.log(url);  
this.displayBookmark();      
}
```

The problem was that I saved empty url to local storage, and because of it I saw console.log(url) empty and I thought that it didn't worked. Turns out I needed to clean my local storage. Glad I solved it in the end.